# Memory usage of an empty List or Dictionary?

Tags: c#, memory

How much memory is used by an empty List or Dictionary? Such as:

```
List<double> list = new List<double>();
```

The pointer itself eats at least 32 bits on x86 and 64 of x64 OS, but what about the list itself? With 0 records.

The reason for asking is, can you save some bytes by setting lists to `null`?

(Imagine you have a class that contains some `List<T>` which in some cases is being used and in other case it is not, in that case having a `boolean` like `IsEmpty` and `null` instead of empty list might save some operating memory. Especially in case you would have thousands of such classes in operating memory, every bit counts.)

Comment: I think your best bet is to use a memory profiler like ANTS and look up these specific objects and their memory usage.

Comment: I don't have money for ants and ATM I am on ubuntu

Comment: I think under almost all circumstances, the answer is “so little it doesn't actually matter”.

Comment: it always matter to me when it comes to memory... If there were less programmers who don't care about memory usage, modern programs wouldn't be so resource expensive...

Comment: @Petr 1. How many empty lists do you have? Unless it's millions, this won't make a measurable difference. 2. If you want to decrease memory consumption of your application, you should use a memory profiler to find out what takes up most memory. Premature optimization is a waste of time (at best), and that applies to optimizing memory too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Decompiled by dotPeek :

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    private T[] _items; //4 bytes for x86, 8 for x64
    private int _size; //4 bytes
    private int _version; //4 bytes
    [NonSerialized]
    private object _syncRoot; //4 bytes for x86, 8 for x64
    private static readonly T[] _emptyArray; //one per type
    private const int _defaultCapacity = 4; //one per type
    ...
}
```

you got total of **20** bytes on x86 (16 for `List<T>` members and 4 for metadata reference overhead) and **32** on x64, including reffernce to type of the object, which each object in .net have. This calculation is done roughly not counting alligment.

---

```
public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : ...
{
    private int[] buckets; //4 bytes for x86, 8 for x64
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Entry[] entries; //4 bytes for x86, 8 for x64
    private int count; //4 bytes
    private int version; //4 bytes
    private int freeList; //4 bytes
    private int freeCount; //4 bytes
    private IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer; //4 bytes for x86, 8 for x64
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection keys; //4 bytes for x86, 8 for x64
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection values; //4 bytes for x86, 8 for x64
    private object _syncRoot; //4 bytes for x86, 8 for x64

    private const string VersionName = "Version"; //one per type
    private const string HashSizeName = "HashSize"; //one per type
    private const string KeyValuePairsName = "KeyValuePairs"; //one per type
    private const string ComparerName = "Comparer"; //one per type
}
```

**44** for x86 and **72** for x64. Again rough calculation, since instances of different objects are required.

Comment: What about the virtual method table?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens isn't it created one per type? `List<T>` has also two static variables, but I didn't count them, because they don't affect the size of the object itself. As far as I remember, each object in .net has only one reference overhead.

Comment: I can't see any point to the question except to measure the cost of dead code, so that would mean count everything. Here is a link of use (titled The Cost of Enumeration in DOT NET, by Joe Duffy): http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2008/09/21/TheCostOfEnumeratingInNET.aspx

Comment: What about the `_items` array?

Comment: @svick as OP stated in question: "How much memory eats **empty** List and Dictionary?".

Comment: Packing is normally 8 on x86 and 16 on 64-bit, so double those numbers  :)

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Yes, but are you sure empty `List` means the array is not actually allocated?

Comment: @svick there is a _static_ empty array `T[0]` that is shared by all empty lists of type `T`. In the default constructor: `_items = _emptyArray;`.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason for asking is, can you save some bytes by setting lists to null?

As a general rule (to which, like any rule, there are exceptions), you shouldn't set managed objects to `null` to free memory.  Instead, leave it to the garbage collector to detect when an object is no longer reachable.  In fact, setting a reference to `null` may be counter-productive as it can actually [slightly extend the lifetime of the object](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/26/should-i-assign-null-to-my-local-variables/).

An exception might be an edge case where it's worth setting a large object to `null` (e.g. a very large list that is a property of another object which for some reason needs to remain reachable), but such cases will be rare and may indicate a "code smell".